# ¿Cómo evitar el duplicado de texto al enviar a la base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

¿Alguien tiene una idea de como evitar el duplicado a la hora de enviar texto a la base de datos?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi formulario

```
     <form id="message-form" style="transform: translate(10px, 10px);">
        <div class="input">
          <input id="message-input" name="message_txt" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="submit-btn">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-message" id="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">
        </div>
      </form>
```

Aquí tengo mi `script` `js` que envía el texto mediante `fetch`

```
  <script>
document.forms['right-Container'].addEventListener('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    let message = document.getElementById('message-form').value;
    if(message !== ''){
        fetch('submitmessage.php?user=<?php echo $_GET['user']; ?>',
            {
                method: 'POST',
                body: {text: message}
            }
        )
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(newMessage => {
            if(newMessage !== ''){
                let div = document.createElement('div');
                div.classList.add('me-cont');
                let innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
                innerDiv.setAttribute('class', 'me bubble-me');
                innerDiv.innerText = newMessage;
                div.append(innerDiv);
                document.getElementById('cont').append(div);
                document.getElementById('message-form').value = '';
            }
        });
    }
});
document.getElementById('message-form').addEventListener('keyup', function(event){
    if(event.keyCode === 13){ // Enter
        document.forms['right-Container'].submit();
    }
});
  </script>
```

Y este es mi archivo `submitmessage.php`

```
<?php session_start();

  if ($_GET['user']) {
    if (isset($_POST['text'])) {
      if ($_POST['text'] !='') {
        $host = "remotemysql.com";
        $userdb = " ";
        $pass = " ";
        $con = mysqli_connect($host, $userdb, $pass, $userdb) or die("ERROR!");
        $sender_name = $_SESSION['user'];
        $resiver_name = $_GET['user'];
        $message = base64_encode($_POST['text']);
        $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $q = "INSERT INTO message (sender_name, resiver_name, message_txt, date_time) VALUES ('".$sender_name."','".$resiver_name."','".$message."','".$date."')";
        $r = mysqli_query($con,$q);
        if ($r) {
            echo json_encode(base64_decode($message));

        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $q . "<br>" . $con->error;

        }
        $con->close();
      }else{
          //Nada
      }
    }
  }

?>
```

¿Alguien tiene idea de como evitar este tipo de `bugs`?
Intenté añadir un contador y modificando un poco el código pero no me funciono.

Lo que quiero lograr es que se envié un mensaje y evitar que se envié el mismo duplicado

> Actualizo mi codigo implementando lo que comento Jorge Solis
>   No incerta el mensaje en la base de datos y me regresa en la url 
>   http://localhost/message.php?user=Guest?message_txt=Prueba&submit=Enviar

Comment: Ese es todo el código de javascript? Lo pregunto por lo que haces con lo que regresa el post, es decir, por qué si la respuesta se inserta en un elemento a través de un id en un elemento, en tu screenshot tienes varios mensajes?

Comment: si es todo el js segui de referencia este video `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RUZgjM7fqlw` en en algunos casos no envia el formulario mediante el codigo que pase

Comment: Es la misma ruta, verdad? En ese caso sucede que estás mandando la información dos veces, una por el javascript y otra por el method="post" de tu form. En la función del listener, agrega un parametro event y antes de la asignación de message_txt, pon
event.preventDefault();
Esto hará que no se recargue la página, por lo que verás el comportamiento que yo te decía (se van a sobreescribir los mensajes, debido a la linea en la que sobreescribes todo el contenido del elemento #cont).

Comment: @JorgeSolis si el archivo esta en la raíz ,  Me podrías pasar un mini ejemplo no me doy cuenta de lo que me comentas

Answer (score 0):

Hoy en día, usar jQuery es mucho menos necesario. Trata de aprender Javascript puro primero y todo será más claro a la hora de comenzar a usar algún framework.

Cambia todo tu código de javascript por:

```
<script>
document.forms['message-form'].addEventListener('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    let message = document.getElementById('message-input').value;
    if(message !== ''){
        data = new FormData();
        data.append('text', message);
        fetch('submitmessage.php',
            {
                method: 'POST',
                body: data
            }
        )
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(newMessage => {
            if(newMessage !== ''){
                let div = document.createElement('div');
                div.classList.add('me-cont');
                let innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
                innerDiv.setAttribute('class', 'me bubble-me');
                innerDiv.innerText = newMessage;
                div.append(innerDiv);
                document.getElementById('cont').append(div);
                document.getElementById('message-input').value = '';
            }
        });
    }
});
document.getElementById('message-input').addEventListener('keyup', function(event){
    if(event.keyCode === 13){ // Enter
        document.forms['message-form'].submit();
    }
});
```

En tu html, borra el atributo `method="post"`

En el php, cambia el if a:

```
if ($r) {
    echo json_encode(base64_decode($message));
} else {
    echo "''";
}
```

EDIT:

Cambia en el javascript

```
fetch('submitmessage.php',
```

Por

```
fetch('submitmessage.php?user=<?php echo $_GET['user']; ?>',
```

Comment: hum no se incerta en la base de datos en la url me lanza `http://localhost/message.php?user=Guest?message_txt=Prueba&submit=Enviar`

Comment: Con la corrección debería quedar, aunque otra opción sería enviar el user por post y leerlo en el post de lado de php

Comment: Me pasa lo mismo ya lo añadi antes de que actualizaras el comentario y pasa lo mismo creo que mejor uso el `action=""` aunque no quería hacer redirecciones ademas ya actualice mi pregunta aplicando tu codigo

Comment: en la consola de DevTool me lanza este error TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

Comment: Ah ok, lo que pasa es que no cuadraban los id de los elementos. Actualicé la respuesta. Intenta con ese código nuevamente

Comment: sigue renviando a ?message_txt=Prueba&submit=Enviar y no lo incerta en la db, el error addEventListener ya no sale en la consola

Comment: ok, el que siga saliendo &submit=Enviar se debe a que tu boton de submit tiene value="Enviar", pero no tendría que estar incluído.
En el html, en el form, pon action="javascript:void(0);"

Comment: Tambien, en revisa que en la pestaña Network del DevTools salga cada request con el mensaje en la parte de Headers, hasta abajo, en Form Data

Comment: ahora no redirige y no envia en la pestaña Network no aparecen los request

Comment: Si no redirige pero tampoco sale nada en Network, entonces no se está mandando el post.
Y si no sale error, quiere decir que el listener del submit sí está funcionando.
Sí cambiaste el id en let message = document.getElementById('message-input').value; ???

Comment: si ya actualice esa linea

Comment: Entonces abajo de esa agrega un console.log(message);
al intentar enviar un mensaje, tendría que salir en la consola lo que esté en el input.

Comment: la consola no lanza nada

Comment: Es un error antes del post. Voy a actualizar la respuesta en un minuto, para no spammear aquí con más comentarios.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97396/discussion-between-max-and-jorge-solis).